# Index outside of bound exception

Tags: c#, exception, dictionary, static

I have the following code, and somehow yesterday evening it had thrown a lot of exceptions:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)

I just don't see how this is possible, I check for null and if the key is available. This is the only method where lastTimeoutCheck is used.

```
private static Dictionary<string, DateTime> lastTimeoutCheck;
private static readonly object CacheLock = new object();
private static void CheckTimeout(string groupName)
{
    if (lastTimeoutCheck == null)
    {
        lastTimeoutCheck = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        return;
    }
    if (!lastTimeoutCheck.ContainsKey(groupName))
    {
        lastTimeoutCheck.Add(groupName, DateTime.UtcNow);
        return;
    }

    if (lastTimeoutCheck[groupName] <
        DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-GroupConfigSection.TimeOutCheckMinutes))
    {
        lock (CheckLock)
        {
            if (lastTimeoutCheck[groupName] <
                DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-GroupConfigSection.TimeOutCheckMinutes))
            {
                GroupHolder groupHolder =
                    (GroupHolder) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(groupName);
                if (groupHolder != null)
                {
                    groupHolder.UpdateTime();
                }

                lastTimeoutCheck[groupName] = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using this method from multiple threads? `Dictionary<,>` is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: If you look at the error message, you'll see that the error is happening at `Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue>.Insert()`. Are you sure that `groupName` has a valid value?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't use any threading.

Comment: @BvdVen then why locking on `CheckLock` ?

Comment: If this is on a website/web service that multiple people are accessing, then it is most likely using multiple threads.

Comment: @Guillaume CheckLock is to make sure the code is not executed while an other user is already running the code.

Comment: @JLRishe hmm ok, that seems plausible, how would I prevent this from happening then?

Comment: @BvdVen just for info. why are you checking below statement twice?

'if (lastTimeoutCheck[groupName] < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-GroupConfigSection.TimeOutCheckMinutes))'

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal one before the lock (is it necessary to lock and continue) and on after the lock is released (is the value already updatd while waiting for the lock to be released)

Comment: `the code executed while an other user is already running the code` So you have multiple threads !

Comment: @Guillaume yes you're right, not a coded thread but because this code is in a website. I didn't realised this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your variable is `static` and the error indicates it runs on a web server, you are most likely facing the problem that two threads access the same value at the same time, resulting in two adds at the same time.

The solution depends on your situation:

1. Don't make the dictionary `static`, if you don't intend it to be shared across sessions. This doesn't really fix the problem. It makes it more unlikely to occur;
2. Use a thread safe dictionary type: [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Wouldn't the lock take care that the dictionary is not changed at the same time?

Comment: @BvdVen: no, because not all access is performed within the lock.

Comment: @BvdVen Yes, if you lock the contents of that entire method, but using locks effectively requires insight and caution. You can't just throw a lock in anywhere you're worried about concurrent access. That could create deadlocks, degraded performance, and so on.

Comment: This statement might still cause issues since it is not inside the `lock`: `lastTimeoutCheck.Add`. It might cause the dictionary to resize and you might loose data in the process.